# Changing number of owners in realmexamples

Tags: swift, realm, owner

I've downloaded Realm and opened the RealmExamples app.

The RealmExamples app is included in the down load from
http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.4/

Trying to add an owner to get the print out to give more than 1. Also added age to print out

```
 println("\(dog.name) has \(ownerNames.count) owners (\(ownerNames)) is \(dog.age) years old")
```

I added a dog and owner and gave one dog two owners but the print gives just 1 owner twice.

```
  import UIKit
import Realm

class Dog: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    var owners: [Person] {
        // Realm doesn't persist this property because it only has a getter defined
        // Define "owners" as the inverse relationship to Person.dogs
        return linkingObjectsOfClass("Person", forProperty: "dogs") as [Person]
    }
}

class Person: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var dogs = RLMArray(objectClassName: Dog.className())
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath(), error: nil)

    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    realm.transactionWithBlock {
        Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["John", [["Fido", 1]]])
        Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["colin", [["Fido", 1]]])
      Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["colin", [["simba", 3]]])
    }

    // Log all dogs and their owners using the "owners" inverse relationship
    let allDogs = Dog.allObjects()
    for dog in allDogs {
        let dog = dog as Dog
        let ownerNames = dog.owners.map { $0.name }
        println("\(dog.name) has \(ownerNames.count) owners \(ownerNames) is \(dog.age) years old")
    }
    return true
}
```

}

the println gives

```
Fido has 1 owners ([John]) is 1 years old
Fido has 1 owners ([colin]) is 1 years old
simba has 1 owners ([colin]) is 3 years old
```

what should I do to get Fido has 2 owners.

Comment: Hey cpmac could you share a bit more code on how your models are set up and how you are querying the database for ownerNames ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the full code of the appdelagate file

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. In this code below, you are creating 3 new people and 3 new dogs.

```
realm.transactionWithBlock {
    Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["John", [["Fido", 1]]])
    Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["colin", [["Fido", 1]]])
  Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["colin", [["simba", 3]]])
}
```

Let's break this down

```
Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["John", [["Fido", 1]]])
```

Is the equivalent of doing this:

```
//Creating our first person and dog relationship
let firstDog = Dog()
firstDog.name = "Fido"
firstDog.age = 1

let person1 = Person()
person1.name = "John"
person1.dogs = [firstDog]
```

Now we look into the next Person and Dog relationship being created

```
//Your original code
Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["colin", [["Fido", 1]]])
```

Is the equivalent of doing this:

```
//Creating our second person and dog relationship
let secondDog = Dog()
secondDog.name = "Fido"
secondDog.age = 1

let person2 = Person()
person2.name = "colin"
person2.dogs = [secondDog]
```

So even though the dogs have the same name and age, they aren't the same object (dog). firstDog != secondDog. I think the easiest way to do this is to write out the long form similar to what I did above and instead do this

```
person2.dogs = [firstDog]
```

Now that refers to the same dog object that was added to the first person.

Alternative solution:

Another way to do it is using primaryKeys, so each dog is unique and you can fetch them by primaryKey before adding them to another person. That solution is a little more involved but normally the right way to do these kinds of operations as they get more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
This code seems to imply that the only link between a dog and owner is the name.

    var owners: [Person] {
            // Realm doesn't persist this property because it only has a getter defined
            // Define "owners" as the inverse relationship to Person.dogs
            return linkingObjectsOfClass("Person", forProperty: "dogs") as [Person]
then
     dynamic var dogs = RLMArray(objectClassName: Dog.className())

Comment: Np! The property dogs is the link since you have a stored relationship
dynamic var dogs on the Person object. 

Dog.className() = "Dog". You might be mistaking that as Dog.className() = the property name on dog (i.e. dog.name), which would be incorrect.

Comment: It is confusing with dog.name person.name. I changed the last transaction line to ["Colin", [["Rex",3]["Fido",1]]] which printed out a forth line - Rex has 1 owner (["Colin"]).

Comment: Correct, each time you are calling  Person.createInRealm... you are literally creating brand new person objects and dog objects even if they have the same name.

The best way to maintain the relationships is to write out your code fully, similar to the answer I have above. This makes it very clear which dog goes with which person. You can also use primary keys which will force you to only have 1 person with a specific ID.

If this doesn't make sense come join the live office hours on Tuesday next week!